# Clone USB-drive bit for bit

Tags: hard-drive, usb, truecrypt, clone

I have a USB-drive that is encrypted with Truecrypt. Now, I'd like to make a copy of it from time to time, so I need a method of cloning the USB.

The two USB-sticks are of same size, brand, and type, if that matters.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dd`.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/<source> of=/dev/<destination>
```

If you want to know how much has been copied already, you may want to run this instead:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/<source> | pv -s <size in GB>G | sudo dd of=/dev/<destination>
```

You may need to install `pv` first.